# Contact Form in sidebar

Tags: widgets, sidebar, plugin-contact-form-7

I have a Contact Form 7 form as a page on my site.  I'd like to place the contact form on the sidebar.  How can I do this?

Comment: Thanks for retagging.  I didn't have the rep to make a tag.

Comment: You can try hidden sidebar like this — http://looks-awesome.com/portfolio/wordpress-plugins/nks-wordpress-contact-form/ That plugin allows to style Contact Form 7. Just put CF7 short code and customise your design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [the options suggested in this WordPress Support thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/contact-form-7-in-sidebar)? They range from copying the generated code in a Text Widget to parsing the shortcode yourself in your template (`<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form 1 "Contact form 1"]'); ?>`).

Comment: I copied the shortcode into a text widget and placed in my sidebar.  `<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form 2 "Case Submission Form"]'); ?>`  The submit works, but the `'); ?> ` shows as text under the form?

Comment: @RememberMe: This is the full PHP code you would use in your template. If you want to try it in a text widget, you only use `[contact-form 2 "Case Submission Form"]`. Someone on the forum noticed this didn't work for him, but the code could have been updated since then.